# Can't see the django home page

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, thus the question.
I've a django project set up with two apps both of which seem to work fine. Just that I can't reach the homepage - which should be the default django page. I get the following error,

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in core.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^aggregator/
^bouncer/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^aggregator/', include('aggregator.urls')),
        url(r'^bouncer/', include('bouncer.urls')),

    ]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: your urlpatterns missing the path to your home
        add 
url(r'^$', views.home)

Comment: How do I add it. I checked a clean project and it only had the path to the admin but it works fine.

Comment: do u have a view for homepage ?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the path to your home directory in the urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^aggregator/', include('aggregator.urls')),
    url(r'^bouncer/', include('bouncer.urls')),
   url(r'^$', views.yourhomeview),

]
```